# How to convert a string of coordinate to a LatLngBound object?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a string corresponding to a rectangle, like so:

```
((x1,y1),x2,y2))
```

I would like to convert it in a LatLngBounds object, and, draw the rectangle by:

```
myRectangle.setBounds(latLngBounds);
```

or

```
myRectangle.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's an interesting string format. I'll bet you're missing a parenthesis and it really looks like this:

```
((x1,y1),(x2,y2))
```

Now the question is what those `x1` etc. values represent. For purposes of discussion, I'll assume that the order is:

```
((s,w),(n,e))
```

It should be obvious how to fix the code if that's not the right order.

A simple way to parse this would be to strip out all the parentheses first, and for safety we'll remove any whitespace at the same time. Then you're left with:

```
s,w,n,e
```

which is easy to split into an array:

```js
// Given a coordString in '((s,w),(n,e))' format,
// construct and return a LatLngBounds object
function boundsFromCoordString( coordString ) {
    var c = coordString.replace( /[\s()]/g, '' ).split( ',' );
    // c is [ 's', 'w', 'n', 'e' ] (with the actual numbers)
    var sw = new google.maps.LatLng( +c[0], +c[1] ),
        ne = new google.maps.LatLng( +c[2], +c[3] );

    return new google.maps.LatLngBounds( sw, ne );
}

var testBounds = boundsFromCoorString( '((1.2,3.4),(5.6,7.8))' );
```

If you're not familiar with the use of `+` in the code like `+c[0]`, that converts a string to a number. It's much like using `parseFloat()`.

I previously posted a more complicated approach. I'll leave it here since the lengthy commented regular expression may be of interest:

```js
var coordString = '((1.2,3.4),(5.6,7.8))';
var match = coordString
    .replace( /\s/g, '' )
    .match( /^\(\((.*),(.*)\),\((.*),(.*)\)\)$/ );
if( match ) {
    var
        s = +match[1],
        w = +match[2],
        n = +match[3],
        e = +match[4],
        sw = new google.maps.LatLng( s, w ),
        ne = new google.maps.LatLng( n, e ),
        bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds( sw, ne );
}
else {
    // failed
}
```

That regular expression in the `.match()` call is a mess, isn't it? Regular expressions are not the most readable language when they're in this one-line format. For clarity, let's break that into multiple lines as you could do in languages like Python or Ruby:

```
.match( /               Start regular expression
    ^                   Beginning of string
        \(              Initial open paren
            \(              Open paren for the first pair
                (.*)            First number
                ,               Comma inside the first pair
                (.*)            Second number
            \)              Close paren for the first pair
            ,               Comma separating the two pairs
            \(              Open paren for the second pair
                (.*)            Third number
                ,               Comma inside the second pair
                (.*)            Fourth number
            \)              Close paren for the second pair
        \)              Final close paren
    $                   End of string
/ );                    End regular expression
```

If the string has no spaces in it, you can leave out this line:

```
    .replace( /\s/g, '' )
```

That's just to remove whitespace before doing the `.match()` for simplicity.

Comment: About the string format: with myRectangle.getBounds() send to a php script. What did you expect ? x1,y1 = NW point, x2,y2 = SE point according to the google doc.

Comment: And could you explain the long match ;-)

Comment: I would never expect something called `x1` to be a North point, nor `y1` to be a South point. Customarily, `x` is the horizontal axis and `y` the vertical, so if you did use names like these, `x1` and `x2` would be the longitudes, and `y1` and `y2` the latitudes. This confusion is why it's best to avoid `x` and `y`-style names in Google Maps code and use names like `lat`, `lng`, `n`, `s`, `e`, and `w` instead. How about an actual example of one of your coordinate strings? That would make it clear what the format really is. Is the actual format `((n,w),(s,e))`? Or what?

Comment: I am wrong. I am using the standard format which is sw,ne and not nw,se ! I was using x,y because it was a theoretical example but I note the possible confusion. What the better for you: to decode in javascript or in php ? and yes, I missed a parenthesis

Comment: Wait - are you generating this string from PHP code of your own? You could generate a JSON object or JavaScript array instead; then you wouldn't need all the regular expression parsing. It would be much simpler that way. I was just answering the question as you stated it; I can't read your mind and understand the greater context unless you tell me. :-) So how about telling some more of the overall story?

Comment: In any case I thought of a much simpler way to do it instead of the complicated regular expression, so now it's not very complicated even with the string format you have now. This often happens that I think of a simple approach after coding a complicated one! :-)

Comment: I send from a js script myRectangle.getBounds() to a PHP script which stores the data in mysql. In mysql the data is ((x,y),(x,y)). Later I fetch this data with PHP and send it to a js script in order to (re)draw the rectangle. My problem is/was to redraw. My last question means: is is better to send from php to js the string or the decoded info (lat/lon).

Comment: In fact the match function is only for the syntax. Only s,w,n,e is important and could be extract by another way but which one ?!

Answer (score -1):

You need to create SouthWest and NorthEast corners using [LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#LatLng). Then you just pass those in to [LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#LatLngBounds). The documentation is pretty thorough.

Comment: I know this part of the process. The first part is to translate the string: how to do it ?